# How to set globally the label of enumerate and enumerate*?

Tags: enumerate, enumitem, inline

in my document I have 2 types of `enumerate` lists. I use `enumerate` for lists like:

> **1.** Item
>
> **2.** Item
>
> **3.** ...

And `enumerate*` for lists like:

> **(a)** Item, **(b)** Item, **(c)** ...

I set globally the `enumerate` using `\setlist[enumerate]{label=\bfseries\arabic*.}` but I can't set globally the `enumerate*` using `\setlist[enumerate*]{label=\bfseries(\alph*)}`. How can I set globally the `enumerate*` environment label?

**Extra question:** How can I set globally `enumerate*` for to add automatically a comma after every item and the word "and" before the last item?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\bfseries\arabic*.}
%\setlist[enumerate*]{label=\bfseries(\alph*)}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate*}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\end{enumerate*}

\begin{enumerate*}[label=\bfseries(\alph*)]
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\end{enumerate*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key `itemjoin` sets the format for in between the items, while the key `itemjoin*` sets the format for before the last item, overriding the `itemjoin` setting.

In order to keep the displayed list numeric while the inline list alphabetical, you would have to create a new list, as the `\enumerate` and `\enumerate*` environments share the same settings.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{inlinelist}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[inlinelist]{label=\bfseries(\alph*), itemjoin={{, }}, itemjoin*={{, and }}} % <-------------
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\bfseries\arabic*.}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 2
        \item Item 3
    \end{enumerate}

    \begin{inlinelist}
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 2
        \item Item 3
    \end{inlinelist}

    \begin{inlinelist}
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 2
        \item Item 3
    \end{inlinelist}
\end{document}
```

[image]