# Set format to custom enumeration

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

My enumeration should contain four key words:

1. Aggregate Power
2. Proximate Power
3. Offensive Power
4. Offensive Intentions

I want to enumerate them and take these four key words as the enumeration label. At the same time I would like to set them as `\textbf{}`.

My attempts were working around the below example:

```
\begin{enumerate}[Label=\textbf{\item[]}]
    \item[Aggregate Power]
    \item[Proximate Power]
    ...
\end{enumerate}
```

I would like to avoid writing `\textbf{}` in every label.

**How can I set an item format for the customized but changing labels?**

Comment: why use `enumerate` if you aren't planning to *enumerate* them? `description` might be more apt here..

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Enumerated description list](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/30029)

Comment: Read more in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/393542).

Comment: @JouleV , your answer unfortunately also only uses numeric values which increment automatically. My items however change the label. How can I set a format for a label?

Comment: @Alex_P I think you want to make global settings for your labels. Am I mistaken? If so, I'm sorry for that.

Comment: `\usepackage{enumitem}` and `\begin{description}[format={\bfseries}] \item[Foo] \item[foobar]\end{description}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, thank you Christian for your code. It is working for me. However, I could not find this code in your duplicate example.